# Get user who have valid records within date range using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a record like this :

```
userId | valid | date
1      | null  | 2018-07-01
1      | 1     | 2018-07-02
1      | 1     | 2018-07-03
1      | 1     | 2018-07-04
1      | 1     | 2018-07-05
2      | null  | 2018-07-01
2      | 0     | 2018-07-02
2      | 0     | 2018-07-03
2      | 1     | 2018-07-04
2      | 1     | 2018-07-05
3      | null  | 2018-07-01
3      | null  | 2018-07-02
3      | 1     | 2018-07-03
3      | 1     | 2018-07-04
3      | 1     | 2018-07-05
```

I want to get user who have perfect valid records from 2018-07-01 to 2018-07-05. 'valid' column with null value will be ignore.

Expected result :

```
userId
1
3
```

Reason why userId #2 not selected is because userId #2 has 2 'valid' column value than equals to 0.

Comment: Do you know how to get users with invalid records within that range?

Comment: Can someone explain this to me? : `Reason why userId #2 not selected is because userId #2 has 2 'valid' column value than equals to 0.`

Comment: @HarshilDoshi - `NULL` and `1` is valid. `0` is not valid.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch So, if a userid has all the values of `valid` as `null`, it should be in output.

Comment: No: *column with null value will be ignore*. `1` is valid, `0` is not valid and `NULL` ignored (but not invalid).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following solution using [`EXISTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```
SELECT DISTINCT userId 
FROM records r1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT userId 
    FROM records r2
    WHERE r1.userId = r2.userId AND IFNULL(valid, 1) = 0 AND `date` BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2018-07-05'
) AND NOT valid IS NULL AND `date` BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2018-07-05';
```

> **demo:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jzh4cEoYXVKfvs6ZmSVhfG/1

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT userId FROM table 
WHERE (date BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2018-07-05') 
AND valid IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY userId
```

Answer (score 0):

How to Test for NULL Values?

It is not possible to test for NULL values with comparison operators, such as =, <, or <>.

We will have to use the IS NULL and IS NOT NULL operators instead.

```
SELECT userId FROM `user` WHERE (date BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2018-07-05')  AND `user.valid` != '0' AND `valid` IS NOT NULL GROUP BY `userId`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not in` operator

```
  SELECT DISTINCT userId 
    FROM your_table t1 
    WHERE  userId not in (
        SELECT userId FROM your_table t2 WHERE t1.userId = t2.userId AND 
      valid =0 AND date >= '2018-07-01' and date<= '2018-07-05'
    )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b8a9d/1

Answer (score 0):

Try Following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userId 
FROM records r1
where 0 not in (
  SELECT valid
  FROM records r2
  WHERE r1.userId = r2.userId 
  AND   valid is not null 
  AND   `date` BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2018-07-05'
  having count(*) > 0
);
```

Please check it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c27a2b/9/0) also.

Note: You'll need to change the mode if it is set to `Only-Group-By` in order to work above query.

Although, following query won't require to change any settings. You can directly run it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT userId 
FROM records r1
where valid is not null
group by userid
having count(*) > 0
and 0 not in ( SELECT valid
               FROM records r2
               WHERE r1.userId = r2.userId 
               AND   valid is not null 
               and   `date` BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2018-07-05'
             )
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c27a2b/14/0) for this particular query

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I see that SO is still very much a code-writing service. Well, here's another, old school, fish...

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.userid
  FROM records x
  LEFT
  JOIN records y
    ON y.userid = x.userid
   AND y.valid = 0
   AND y.date BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2018-07-05'
 WHERE x.date BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2018-07-05'
   AND y.userid IS NULL;
```